# Error: month must be in 1..12: 03292021 (mmddyyyy) in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a column in my pandas data frame containing dates in the format 'mmddyyyy' with object datatype Eg - 03292021,06262021,01282020....

I'm trying to convert this column into a date column with the format 'mm/dd/yyyy'. Eg - 03/29/2021

Example of the code that I've tried is below:

```
df['datecol'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datecol'])
df['datecol'] = df['datecol'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```

which gives me the error

> month must be in 1..12: 03292021

What changes should be made in the code to get the desired output?

Comment: Use `df['datecol'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datecol'], format='%m%d%Y')`

Comment: Also not that you don't need the intermediate assignment, you can do `df['datecol'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datecol'], format='%m%d%Y').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')`

Comment: Or even: `df['datecol'].str.replace('(..)(..)..(..)', r'\1/\2/\3', regex=True)`

Comment: The datatype still shows as 'object'. Why so? How should I change it to 'datetime'?